# How to filter Core Data objects with NSPredicate based on array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

Let's say I have some data inside Core Data based on the following object:

```
class TestObject {
   var name: String
   var type: String
}
```

`type` can have one of the following names: "red", "green", "blue", "black".

Now I want to filter my data not based on one type, but an array of types, something like this:

```
public static func typePredicate(types: [String]) -> NSPredicate {

    return NSPredicate(format: "type == %@", types) // this line should test for an array of types, not one type
}
```

Is this possible to do with `NSPredicate` ?

Comment: You're looking for the IN keyword. Ex. ("type IN %@", types); Here's a reference if you would like to read further: [Using Predicates with Arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like below

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@",object.field,types]
```

EDIT:
In Swift

```
var types = ["Red","Blue","Green"]
var predicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY %K IN %@", 
                               argumentArray: [object.field, types])
```